hyperlink does not appear in index when different counter is used
I am trying to create a bibliographical document which contents several entries and an index at the end.
I wanted my index to refer entry-numbers instead of page-number, which I could manage to do. But now the problem is the index entries do not show the hyperlinks to the entry-numbers as the usually do when they refer to page number.

Is there any way to have hyperlinks to the counters shown in index entries?
here is my MWE (which is somewhat long. I am sorry for that.).
I have compiled the following code using lualatex and upmendex with mr-sorting-ist file. This file contains just this much text : icu_locale "mr_IN".
The order of compiling is as follows:

lualatex file.tex

upmendex -s mr-sorting-ist *idx

lualatex file.tex

lualatex file.tex
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{marathi}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcounter{ln}
\setcounter{ln}{1}
\newcounter{leno}
\counterwithin{leno}{ln}
\NewDocumentCommand{\lekhno}{}   {\refstepcounter{leno}\theleno}
\NewDocumentCommand{\lekh}{ m}{%
\noindent \textbf{\lekhno\ }
{\textbf{#1} }
\newline
}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[%
title     = {व्यक्तिनामसूची},%
name      = {V},%
noautomatic%
]
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Index}1{\imki@wrindexentry{V}{#1}{\theleno}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\lekh{विष्णुशास्त्री चिपळूणकरांच्या\Index{चिपळूणकर विष्णु कृष्ण} पुढाकाराने काढलेल्या न्यू इंग्लिश स्कूलची\Index{न्यू इंग्लिश स्कूल} ५० वर्षे- योग्यता. त्यांच्या निबंधमालेनंतर\Index{निबंधमाला} निघालेल्या निबंधचंद्रिकेत\Index{निबंधचंद्रिका} वाद उपलब्ध- संमतिवयाच्या वादातील भूमिकेमुळे विष्णुशास्त्री समाजसुधारणेचे कट्टर शत्रू होते असा अपसमज.}
\lekh {निबंधमाला, व त्या आधीची दंभहारक\Index{दंभहारक}, विविध ज्ञान विस्तार, ज्ञानसंग्रह\Index{ज्ञानसंग्रह} या मासिकांची तुलना- निबंधमालेतील विचारप्रवाह व लोकस्थितीचे वर्णन.}
\lekh {विष्णुशास्त्री चिपळूणकरांच्या सामाजिक सुधारणांविषयक\Index{सामाजिक सुधारणा} धरसोड वृत्तीचे सोदाहरण दिग्दर्शन}
\printindex[V]
\end{document}



the example doesn't work for me, makeindex rejects all entries.

@UlrikeFischer I have corrected the access. Now you can view it

no, I won't go to some external google drive to debug something. The example you show here must show the problem.

Sorry. I will try to add the file here.

@UlrikeFischer I have added the image in my post.

I get a lot of Illegal Arabic digit: position 2 in the makeidnex log

an image is not enough. You must show something that we can compile and that allows us to reproduce the problem.

@UlrikeFischer I have added the information that will help to run the MWE I have provided in my post.                           I have compiled the MWE code using lualatex and upmendex with mr-sorting-ist file. This file contains just this much text : icu_locale "mr_IN".
The order of compiling is as follows:

lualatex file.tex
upmendex -s mr-sorting-ist *idx
lualatex file.tex
lualatex file.tex


Try something like this, it relies on your entry numbers not to look like page numbers!
\documentclass{memoir}    
 \usepackage{marathi}

 \newcounter{ln}
 \setcounter{ln}{1}
 \newcounter{leno}
 \counterwithin{leno}{ln}
\NewDocumentCommand{\lekhno}{}   {\refstepcounter{leno}\MakeLinkTarget[page]{leno}\theleno}
\NewDocumentCommand{\lekh}{ m}{%
      \noindent \textbf{\lekhno\ } 
  {\textbf{#1} }
   \newline
   }

 \usepackage{imakeidx}    
 
 \makeindex[%
  title     = {व्यक्तिनामसूची},%
  name      = {V},%
  noautomatic%
 ]    
 \makeatletter    
 \newcommand{\Index}[1]{\imki@wrindexentry{V}{#1|hyperpage}{\theleno}}     
 \makeatother
 \usepackage{hyperref}

 \begin{document}

 \lekh{विष्णुशास्त्री चिपळूणकरांच्या\Index{चिपळूणकर विष्णु कृष्ण} पुढाकाराने काढलेल्या न्यू इंग्लिश स्कूलची\Index{न्यू इंग्लिश स्कूल} ५० वर्षे- योग्यता. त्यांच्या निबंधमालेनंतर\Index{निबंधमाला} निघालेल्या निबंधचंद्रिकेत\Index{निबंधचंद्रिका} वाद उपलब्ध- संमतिवयाच्या वादातील भूमिकेमुळे विष्णुशास्त्री समाजसुधारणेचे कट्टर शत्रू होते असा अपसमज.}

 \lekh {निबंधमाला, व त्या आधीची दंभहारक\Index{दंभहारक}, विविध ज्ञान विस्तार, ज्ञानसंग्रह\Index{ज्ञानसंग्रह} या मासिकांची तुलना- निबंधमालेतील विचारप्रवाह व लोकस्थितीचे वर्णन.}

 \lekh {विष्णुशास्त्री चिपळूणकरांच्या सामाजिक सुधारणांविषयक\Index{सामाजिक सुधारणा} धरसोड वृत्तीचे सोदाहरण दिग्दर्शन}

 \printindex[V]    
\end{document}


Thanks a lot !!!
